# i want to show particular contents of view onclick of dropdown values without storing in database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to show  particular contents of view onclick of dropdown values without storing in database
controller code is :

```
public ActionResult GuideView(int id)
    {
        HeaderViewModel model = new HeaderViewModel();
        model.Guild = id;
        return View(model);

    }
```

navigation bar :

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base")?id=1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Diamond <b class="caret"></b></a>
 <a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base", new { id = 2 })" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Emerald <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

view is:

```
@if (Model.Guild == 1)
   {

  Diamond Carat Weight
  <p>Carat: This one is easy: the bigger the diamond, the more it s worth and the more it costs (all other factors being equal). Diamonds are often listed with a per carat price, especially when buying on the internet or wholesale.<p>
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: i just want to know if this is proper way to do that @Wheels73

Comment: i try this but code does showing any thing,the view is not calling controller

Comment: You don't need the <a href.! Just write @Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base", new { id = 2 }) .. this renders the link for you!

Comment: but  <a href.! is necessary coz its written inside the dropdown

Comment: Ah. i see... you're creating bootstrap links from a drop down...You can use the data-action attribute!.. i'll post and example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, for a link in the view use...

```
@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base", new { id = 2 })
```

If you are using bootstrap to create a list of dropdowns that launch an option, you can use the below.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle user-state:active" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu Options</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a id="lnkMyOption1" class="dropdownitem" data-action="/Base/GuideView?id=1">Diamond</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a id="lnkMyOption2" class="dropdownitem" data-action="/Base/GuideView?id=2">Emerald</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

OK.. Then add the Jquery below to launch to the controller action.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdownitem").on('click', function () {

           var route = $(this).data("action");
           window.location = route;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Post the View code you have now.. and I'll have a look shortly.

Comment: still view not calling controller

Comment: <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base", new { id = 2 })" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Diamond <b class="caret"></b></a>
                </li>
                                                                                                                  <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base", new { id = 2 })" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Emerald <b class="caret"></b></a>
                </li>

Comment: @RajatZade - I've edited my answer to reflect your controller and action. Try that. If it doesn't then you need to debug. Press F12 to to see any errors!

Comment: @RajatZade - hang on.. I think i may have missed something! :)

Comment: @RajatZade - Sorry... i forgot the Jquery to launch the route passed in from the data-action attribute.... I've edited my answer. I've tested and it works.